# Office Script for excel available available for this "Microsoft 365 Business Basic"

Tags: office365, office365-apps, office-scripts

I am using TRIAL version of Microsoft 365 Business Basic.

Is Office Script for excel available available for this "Microsoft 365 Business Basic"?

If yes, how do I activate it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got email from microsoft support

As per them, office script is NOT available with cheapest office 365 plan, that I had purchased, on 20-jul-2022, namely "Microsoft 365 Business Basic".

Office Script is available only in "Microsoft 365 Apps for business" and onwards.

Sadly, microsoft's product price page ( see - https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-365/business/compare-all-microsoft-365-business-products-b ) should clearly mention that OfficeScript / Automation is NOT available in  "Microsoft 365 Business Basic" plan.

I upgraded to higher plan.

And there is one more problem --- a small error in enabling OfficeScript, and even after fixing it, it takes hours before AUTOMATE tab to come. So one needs to careful while enabling Office Script.

Comment: Hey Rahul, can you explain in more detail about the issue that you experienced when enabling Office Scripts. I am on the Office Scripts team and would love to understand more so we can try to solve this issue in the future. Thanks!

Comment: (1) first, I had "Microsoft 365 Business Basic". It does not have OfficeScript. And imo ( imo = in my opinion), it should have been clearly stated. But it was not very explicit.
-------
(2) So when I found that "Microsoft 365 Business Basic" doesnt support OfficeScript, I upgraded to "Microsoft 365 Apps for Business". So I saw OfficeScript link in settings. I saw that it was enabled. But there was no "Automate" tab in Excel !!! So I did lot of manuvering --- like logging out and logging in. And I disabled OfficeScript and re-enabled it and so on. But "Automate" tab didnt appear

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Office Scripts should be enabled by default for the second license that you tried, so we will look into this issue more. Currently, Office Scripts is only available for edu and commercial licenses with access to the desktop applications. If you want to see Office Scripts available for more licenses, let us know where you would most like to see Office Scripts here: http://aka.ms/ExcelSuggestions. Thanks again!